# Using MAX485 with a full duplex device

Tags: rs485, duplex

I have MAX485 board. [MAX485](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX1487-MAX491.pdf) is a half duplex 485 IC.  There are A&B pins.
The device which i should communicate it has the following pin diagram.
[image]
I think this is full-duplex interface. Can i communicate with it using MAX485?
Which pins of TEC3000 device should be connect to A&B pins of MAX485?
NOTE: TEC3000 waits a query like "*IDN?" and response immediately. Do i manage DE&RE pins for switching first TX mode after RX mode?

Installation diagram in the datasheet. There's no specific detail about half/full duplex usage.
[image]

Comment: What's a "TEC3000" and how does the manual say to connect it?

Comment: It doesn't say how to connect to MAX485 of course. It has RS485 to RS422 converter, but i don't have orginal converter. I add a installation diagram to my post.

Comment: If remote is non-switchable FD then they cannot be combined into HD, then you need MAX488 at least